# Run code for all POST PUT DELETE in web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api

So I have a asp.net webapi controller that handles a lot of POSTs and PUTs with various routes.  I also have an authorization level of read-only.  There doesn't seem to be an AuthorizeAttribute for deny.

Instead of denying access inside each route function, where can I put the authorization code so that it only runs for POSTs, PUTs and DELETEs?

Thanks, AD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the authorization in a MessageHandler which is run for all requests and then only do the auth logic where the method != GET.